# Doing Pushups without taking enough protein

Tags: strength-training, protein, push-ups

I will join a gym for strength training after 30 days, so until that time, if i do pushups daily , will it help me in gym ? because currently i am taking only 25-**30gms** of **protein**/day, once  i start gym, i will take more than **80gms**/day ,

so if start pushups now, will it help me to do more pushups after a month ? or its waste of doing pushups now as i am not taking required amount of proteins now....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will see a benefit from starting doing push-ups now. Most people don't need to worry about providing excess protein for their system, and a lot of repetitive bodyweight exercises like push-ups are as much about getting your body to accept the movement than any buildup of muscle.